# Pagination for Hubs with 100+ Projects

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

When sending request to the [**hubs/:hub_id/projects**](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/) endpoint, I am only able to retrieve the first 100 projects. I have tried adding the pagination parameters mentioned [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/pagination/) but the response from the server is still the same. Is there any way to access the rest of these projects?

Comment: Does the response contain a `next` link in the top-level `links` section?

Comment: @SimonD. the top level links section just contains an href that looks like this
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/:hubid/projects"
        }
    }

Comment: I just realized that the GetProjects endpoint doesn't support pagination yet - that feature is under development right now (with ticket FDM-1933).

Until then, you should get **all** projects in the response, provided they are active.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Forge DM now supports pagination feature on BIM360 projects while calling API [GET hubs/:hub_id/projects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/), please check here [Project and Data Service Pagination](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/pagination/#project-and-data-service-pagination), but there is a maximum item limit 100 for each page, so you can obtain 100 projects per page. if your project quantity exceeds 100, you will see a `next` attribute in `links` of the API response like below, then you can get next 100 projects in the next page via calling the URL in the `next` attribute.

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/{HUB_ID}/projects"
        },
        "first": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/{HUB_ID}/projects?page[number]=0&page[limit]=100"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/{HUB_ID}/projects?page[number]=1&page[limit]=100"
        }
    },
    "data": [
        {
        }
     ]
}
```

==========

Unfortunately, the pagination feature is not available for BIM360 projects via calling API [GET hubs/:hub_id/projects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/) now, and it has been logged as `FDM-1769` and `FDM-1933`. As @Simon D. said, you will get all active projects in the response currently before this feature has been implemented.

Comment: thanks. I believe this was a fringe case where there were only 100 active projects. It's working as expected.

Comment: @jcapps Your request is now supported by our Forge DM API, may I ask you a favor to have a try? Feel free to contact me if there is something wrong. Thanks!